# Prove that $ \frac{x}{y} + \frac{y}{z} + \frac{z}{x}=1 $ has no solutions in positive integers $ x,y,z $

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> Prove that $ \frac{x}{y} + \frac{y}{z} + \frac{z}{x}=1 $ has no solutions in positive integers $ x,y,z  $

I got this problem on [brainly.in](https://brainly.in/question/39783764). They have no solutions about this.

I tried to solve it, here my attempt.

$$
\begin{split}
\frac{x}{y} + \frac{y}{z} + \frac{z}{x} &= 1 \quad \text{multiply by } xyz \\
x^2z + y^2x + z^2y -xyz &= 0\\
x \left( zx+y^2 - xy \right) + z^2 y &= 0
\end{split}
$$

From here i need to prove $ xz + y^2 -xz \geq 0 $  but i am failed to do so.

How can i prove it further?

Comment: Hint:  you'd need each summand to be $<1$.

Comment: WLOG, $x\ge y\ge z\ge1$.

Comment: Should note: many of  the proofs given in the duplicate seem too complicated.  Since each summand would have to be $<1$ we get $x<y<z<x$.

Comment: The best answer at that link is the one with no votes (best by virtue of being simplest), and is essentially the same as the comment of @YvesDaoust, although it is also the only one that has no votes so far.

Comment: Just use AM-GM, it doesn't have solutions in positive reals.

Comment: @lulu Sir understand it.

Comment: @MartinR offcourse that one is helpful